# How to union with an array and maintain portability?

Tags: c++, arrays, unions

I am trying to extract a series of 5-bit chunks of data from an array of bytes; or, essentially, read a byte array as if it were an array of 5-bit chunks. An illustration of this idea can be seen below:

[image]

Since the least common multiple of 5-bits and 8-bits is 40-bits, I created a union of 8 5-bit chunks and a 5-element byte array as follows:

```
union Converter {
    struct {
        uint32_t chunk0 : 5;
        uint32_t chunk1 : 5;
        uint32_t chunk2 : 5;
        uint32_t chunk3 : 5;
        uint32_t chunk4 : 5;
        uint32_t chunk5 : 5;
        uint32_t chunk6 : 5;
        uint32_t chunk7 : 5;
    } __attribute__((packed));
    struct {
        uint8_t bytes[5];
    };
};
```

Note that the value of each chunk will be later stored in a 32-bit unsigned integer, hence a `uint32_t` is used to store the value of each chunk in the converter. The idea behind this technique is that I can simply read the values for each of the chunks from the first structure and obtain the associated chunk values. In order to assign the byte array to the union, I used the following:

```
// Create an array of values
uint8_t someArray[5] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};

// Create a coverter
Converter converter;

// Copy the byte array into the converter
std::memcpy(converter.bytes, someArray, 5);
```

Then the chunk values will be read off as follows:

```
std::cout << "Chunk 0: " << converter.chunk0 << std::endl;
std::cout << "Chunk 1: " << converter.chunk1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "Chunk 2: " << converter.chunk2 << std::endl;
// Continue to the remaining chunks...
```

The issue arises with the value of the last chunk: Each of the 0-6 chunks evaluate to `31`, which is correct, but the last chunk evaluates to `7`. Instead, it should be `31`. Looking at the memory (note: I am using an x64 machine, and therefore, little-endian), I see the following values:

```
Address           0 - 3     4 - 7     8 - B     C - F               
000000000024FE20  FFFFFFFF  FF000000  49194000  00000000
```

Interestingly, if I change the value of the first two blocks of memory (a block being a 4-byte group) to `FFFFFFFF FF010000` (changing the second group from `FF000000` to `FF010000`), the value of the last chunk changes from `7` to `15`. In order for the value of `31` to be obtained for the last chunk, the two blocks must be set to `FFFFFFFF FF070000`.

Since 5 bytes and 8 5-bit chunks should directly overlap, assuming no padding, where am I mistaken in my implementation? In this particular case, I am constrained to using C++98 and am attempting to achieve maximal efficiency.

Comment: `std::bitset` perhaps?

Comment: To start with, using unions to "convert" between types is UB.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and in other circumstances, I would agree. Unfortunately, I am constrained to using only C++98 compliant code. Apart from this constraint, I am also attempting to achieve the maximum efficiency possible.

Comment: The simplest solution is often the best. Use `uint8_t[N]` as your underlying data structure and write an algorithm to extract the ith 5-bit number from it.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Would the overhead of performing shifts and masking add any noticeable inefficiencies? This algorithm is performed often, and therefore, I am trying to make it is efficient as I can. I currently have an implementation similar to what you have mentioned, but I wanted to see if I could squeeze more efficiency from the current solution.

Comment: @unseenghost WIth your bit-struct, shifts and mask are used too, it's just that the compiler hides it from you.

Comment: @unseenghost: What overhead? Those operations have to happen one way or another...

Comment: That's a fair point (about the compiler performing the operations). My focus is: Does me doing it manually induce any overhead above and beyond the logic created by the compiler? I.e., will doing it manually be less efficient than the compiler generated code?

Comment: @unseenghost After the usual compiler optimizations, probably there won't be any difference. [To say for sure, a look at the asm output is necessary, which depends not only on the code, but your compiler and flags.]

Comment: @deviantfan Thanks. I can look at the generated ASM if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit field format in C++ does not guarantee no padding. It probably refuses to split your five bit chunk across two 32-bit ints with your compiler.

You will need to write your own unmangler.